# Existential vs Universal Quantification

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

What is the difference and how can I write these two statements in both forms?

> Not in every hole lives a pigeon.
>
> Some pigeon lives in more than one hole.

For the first statement I have $∀h∀p [LivesIn(p, h)]$ but I am not sure how to express this in the universal form.

I am not sure how to express the second statement, because it says "more than one", so a for all wouldn't make sense (at least from what I understand (which is very little))

Also, if you combine a for all and a there exists then what is it, existential or universal? If anybody can help clear the air on these problems for me I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: Please help me out, I'm desperate for anything

Answer (score 2):

For the first, "Not in every hole lives a pigeon", start from the positive assertion, "In every hole lives a pigeon." The one which you're trying to represent is just the negation of that. "In every hole lives a pigeon" is a universal-existential sentence: "for every hole, there's a pigeon that lives in it", or symbolically, $\forall h \exists p\,(Hole(h) \to (Pigeon(p) \wedge LivesIn(p, h)))$. Negating this, moving the negation across the quantifiers and transforming the propositional matrix of the sentence gives the following:
$$
\begin{align}
&\neg \forall h \exists p\,(Hole(h) \to (Pigeon(p) \wedge LivesIn(p, h))) \\
\iff &\exists h \forall p\,\neg(Hole(h) \to (Pigeon(p) \wedge LivesIn(p, h))) \\
\iff &\exists h \forall p\,(Hole(h) \wedge \neg (Pigeon(p) \wedge LivesIn(p, h))) \\
\iff &\exists h \forall p\,(Hole(h) \wedge (Pigeon(p) \to \neg LivesIn(p, h))) \\
\end{align}
$$
In other words, "There's a hole in which no pigeon lives."

For the second sentence, "Some pigeon lives in more than one hole": "some" should signal "existential quantifier" to you. In order to express "more than one", just (in)equality. Like so:
$$
\exists p\,(Pigeon(p) \wedge \exists h_1 \exists h_2\, (Hole(h_1) \wedge Hole(h_2) \wedge h_1 \neq h_2 \wedge LivesIn(p, h_1) \wedge LivesIn(p, h_2))
$$
That is, "There is a pigeon $p$, and there are distinct holes $h_1, h_2$ such that $p$ lives in both $h_1$ and $h_2$."

***Note*** that combining existential and universal quantifiers gives a new thing: the meaning is in general distinct from the meaning of any purely existential or purely universal sentence. Furthermore, order matters: $\forall \exists$ is very different from $\exists \forall$. Three alternating quantifiers is yet another level of complexity, not reducible two-quantifier forms. And so on.

Comment: This makes sense, however, I must show the existential and universal form for EACH sentence. That's what I don't get.

Comment: To be honest with you, I don't get it either in the case of the 1st sentence -- what could it possibly mean? :) "Not in some hole lives a pigeon?" I.e. "There's some hole that no pigeon lives in"... go with that. // In the case of the second sentence, probably the desired universal version is: "Every pigeon lives in more than one hole." Can you render that symbolically? Use implication instead of conjunction after $Pigeon(p)$.

Comment: In the second sentence, you specify hole 1 and hole 2, but it simply says more than 1.

Comment: And in the first sentence, you combine for all and there exists so as you said in the last paragraph it's no longer existential or universal right? I would need a statement that is just one or the other.

Comment: That's right, it doesn't say there are ONLY two, it just says there are at least two distinct holes. More than just one, and not zero. It would be possible to say "there are exactly two" using another clause, but that's not what the sentence means.

Comment: Yes, the first sentence is an $\forall \exists$ ("AE") sentence, neither purely existential nor purely universal.

Comment: So then it doesn't work for what I need.. How would I make it so it's one or the other?

Comment: I assume you were assigned the weird 1st sentence and didn't make it up yourself. So aren't you stuck with it?

Comment: Yes, I am required to write "Not in every hole lives a pigeon." in both existential and universal form. The same thing with the second sentence. I understand everything you're saying but I am still puzzled when it comes to writing the sentences in those forms.

Comment: What do you mean by "universal form"?

Comment: "one using an existential quantifier and one using a universal quantifier" is directly what the assignment reads.

Comment: I'd say use "There's some hole that no pigeon lives in" for the existential version of the 1st sentence. The universal version of the 2nd is (presumably) "Every pigeon lives in more than one hole". Try to work these out as variants of my answer.

Comment: I need an existential and a universal for both sentences..

Comment: There: I'm edited my answer, the first sentence is different (and now correct -- oops!/sorry!).

Comment: I'm still very, very, very confused. The sentence still uses both a for all and a there exists. It needs to be purely existential, and purely universal.

Comment: You cannot express the first sentence using only universal or only existential quantifers.

Answer (score 0):

The second statement is saying that 'there exists a pidgeon who lives in more than one hole" unless you actually meant to write pidgeons.

Comment: I understand this, but I do not know how to write it in predicate logic form in both existential and universal.

Answer (score 0):

> Not in every hole lives a pigeon.

Negate "in every hole lives a pigeon".

$$\neg \;\forall x\;\exists y\; \Big(\operatorname{Hole}(x) \,\to\, \big(\operatorname{Pigeon}(y)\wedge\operatorname{LivesIn}(y, x)\big)\Big)$$

*Remember:* use implication to restrict a universe and conjugation to restrict an existence.

Then use the law of dual negation to 'flip' the quantifiers to the required state, such as:

$$\exists x\;\neg \;\exists y\; \Big(\operatorname{Hole}(x) \,\to\, \big(\operatorname{Pigeon}(y)\wedge\operatorname{LivesIn}(y, x)\big)\Big)$$

> Some pigeon lives in more than one hole.

Declare the existence of (at least) two entities which are not the same thing, … and other stuff.

$$\exists x\,\exists y\,\exists z\;\Big(y\neq z\wedge\ldots\Big)$$

Comment: According to BrianO the first predicate logic you wrote using both for all and there exists so it is neither existential nor universal. I need the sentences in those forms.

Comment: Use the Law of Dual Negation to 'flip' the required quantifiers.

Comment: Thank you, the first sentence's forms make sense. How would I do the second one?

Answer (score 0):

> Not in every hole lives a pigeon.

$\neg \forall x:[Hole(x)\implies \exists y:[Pigeon(y) \land LivesIn(y,x)]]$

Or equivalently:

$\exists x: [Hole(x) \land \forall y: [Pigeon(y)\implies \neg LivesIn(y,x)]]$

> Some pigeon lives in more than one hole.

$\exists x,y,z: [Pigeon(x) \land Hole(y) \land Hole(z) \land [LivesIn(x,y) \land Lives(x,z) \land y\neq z]]$